# IDangerous Swiper duplicates

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, carousel, swiper.js

I'm using Swiper in an Angular+Ionic App with new directive:

```
<ion-slides class="portafoglio-slider"  options="options" slider="slider">
<ion-slide-page ng-repeat="card in cards">
<div class="portafoglio-img">
<img ng-src="{{card.src}}">
<p class="pan-card">{{card.pan}}</p>
</div>
</ion-slide-page>
</ion-slides></code>
```

Then I need to change all (or some) images after slider is loaded.

I use this sample code to replace all images:

```
$scope.setNewImages = function (){
      for (var j=0; j < $scope.cards.length; j++) {
          $scope.cards[j].src ="http://lorempixel.com/1200/800/sports/1/";   
          console.log("Modifico l'immagine numero "+j);  
           $scope.swiper.update();
      }
    }
```

The real problem is the loop system that duplicates slides on slider initialization and the update() method does not replace the duplicates but only normal slides.

So when I reach the end (or the beginning) of the slider I see old images.

Any help?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your slider JS code? Or put it in a JSFiddle or CodePen? Personally I found the duplicates strange and don't quite understand why it does that.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution? Please share.